# Route53 SERVFAIL

Tags: amazon-web-services, dns, amazon-route53

```
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: SERVFAIL, id: 17438
;; flags: qr rd ra; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1232
; OPT=15: 00 16 61 74 20 64 65 6c 65 67 61 74 69 6f 6e 20 74 72 61 76 69 73 73 61 6c 6d 6f 6e 2e 63 6f 6d 2e ("..at delegation travissalmon.com.")
; OPT=15: 00 17 32 30 35 2e 32 35 31 2e 31 39 33 2e 31 34 37 3a 35 33 20 72 63 6f 64 65 3d 52 45 46 55 53 45 44 20 66 6f 72 20 74 72 61 76 69 73 73 61 6c 6d 6f 6e 2e 63 6f 6d 20 41 ("..205.251.193.147:53 rcode=REFUSED for travissalmon.com A")
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;travissalmon.com.      IN  A

;; Query time: 123 msec
;; SERVER: 1.1.1.1#53(1.1.1.1)
;; WHEN: Sat Mar 11 12:39:32 EST 2023
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 143
```

I am attempting the cloud resume challenge, so I am standing up a website using some of these requirements
[List of some requirements for the challenge](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nWxFY.png)

Im not sure why I am getting a "status: SERVFAIL" when I run a dig command on my domain name. How should I go about correcting this. I read that the rcode= refused means **the DNS name server refuses to perform operations for policy reasons.** But I havent altered any policies for my domain name.

Comment: This most likely means you've put  nameservers in your registered domain that are not willing to respond to the request.  Make sure the NS values for your Route53 domain are accurately represented in registration dns records.  `whois` tells me your dns servers are set to `Name Server: NS-1199.AWSDNS-21.ORG
Name Server: NS-831.AWSDNS-39.NET
Name Server: NS-1880.AWSDNS-43.CO.UK
Name Server: NS-403.AWSDNS-50.COM` but those must be wrong as they refuse the request.

Comment: If you registered the domain on Route53 Domains it will automatically create a hosted zone and those nameservers will be set on the domain regsitration side.  If you then went in and removed that hosted zone and created a new one, you have to set the new nameservers on the registration side

Comment: You have no SOA record.  You shouldn't modify anything Route53 created for you.

Comment: @erik258 yes you are correct, my Name Servers are incorrect as to what I have in my registration side. Thank you. Do you think this could also be the reason my ACM certificate was stuck in "pending validation" status when using the DNS validation method?

Comment: It's likely.   Automatic DNS validation uses a CNAME that must be added to the correct Route 53 Zone so DNS resolution is part of the verification.   I would retry the ACM DNS validation or cancel and request a new certificate or whatever it takes.